# How to visualize simplex?

Tags: visualization, simplex

Let's say I have n-simplex and a grid on it. For every point of the grid I evaluate a function. But I truly don't know how to visalize the data received by this evaluation.

Would you help me with any approach to represent a simplex in 3-D or 2-D, which is quite good for an interpretation? Of course it's allowed for representation to be not quite accurate.

Comment: I'm not sure this should be an SO question.. but have you considered using colors to represent the evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the number of each poly tonic faces for the n-simplex using the pascal triangle.
Give a colour to each of the face.combine them by a convex hull.

Comment: can you provide more detailed answer the OP can follow

Comment: Hey,
if you have the dimension as the input.you can find the number of each poly tonic faces.for example for 4-simplex
0-faces-5
1-faces-10
2-faces-10
3-faces-5
4-faces-1.
By using the java awt package or swing tou can create a Graphical User interface(GUI) through which you can assign a different colour to each face by incrementing the HEX value of a colour.Thus you can differentiate each face with a different colour.It gets difficult when the dimensions of the simplex is increased as it is not recommended to display  a 7 dimension figure in 2D or 3D.